# USA Split Phase considerations?

Tags: transformer, electricity

Much of USA residential is split phase, 120V x 2 and neutral. It’s my understanding the phase difference is 180 degrees of time domain.  How are the split phase legs combine to equal 220V?

Related: Do water heaters, dryers or stoves just use half the legs in separate circuits operating at 120V or are the legs somehow combine?

Thank you

Comment: A 220-240V outlet consists of 2 110-120V lines 180 out of phase like you said. So when one line is at its peak of 120V the other is at its minimum of -120V so there is a total of 240V between them. They are both referenced to Neutral. I'm not sure exactly what you are asking in the second part

Comment: We are sloppy about voltages. Sometimes we say it is 110V, sometimes 120, or, occasionally, 117. These are all referring to the same thing, though. Likewise, some people say "220" and some say "240." I usually say 120 and 240. The other thing you may encounter is 120/208. I have seen this in commercial buildings. They have 208 three phase power. So each phase to neutral is 120. But phase to phase is 208. Such buildings don't have 240V outlets, but they may have a 208V outlet.

Comment: And people may call the 208V outlet a 220 or 240V outlet without ever knowing or caring that it is really 208, and without every measuring it.

Comment: Think of the US 2 x 110 VAC supply as a centre tapped 220 VAC transformer with the centre tap grounded. This gives the 180 degree phase relationship.

Comment: I've heard 550 when referring to 600V. The difference is the same as the 220/240 and 110/120 ratio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Much of USA residential is split phase, 120V x 2 and neutral. It’s my understanding the phase difference is 180 degrees of time domain. How are the split phase legs combine to equal 220V?

Assume the neutral is at 0V.  Bear in mind that voltages are always measured between two points.  Often, you measure the voltage between one point and another point that you have declared to be 0V.  But you don't have to - you can measure the voltage between any point in the circuit and any other if you want to.

The first phase is alternating between about +170V and -170V, relative to neutral, with an RMS (root-mean-square) voltage of 120V. (170V is 120V times the square root of 2).  The second phase is also doing the same thing.   But since it is out of phase, when the first phase is positive, the second is negative, and *vice versa*.  So the voltage **measured between one phase and the other** is going between +340V and -340V, with an RMS value of 240V.

*The supply voltage is actually around 110 to 120V, so the phase-to-phase voltage is around 220 to 240V.  There's always a tolerance on the supply voltage.*

> Related: Do water heaters, dryers or stoves just use half the legs in separate circuits operating at 120V or are the legs somehow combine?

That's up to the appliance manufacturer.  In many cases, it's possible to connect a load between one phase and the other, ignoring the neutral.

Comment: @mkeith Quite right - I will fix it.

Answer (score 0):

They actually combine to equal 240 VAC, as you probably expected. The line-to-neutral voltage at a house is 120 VAC nominal, with line-to-line voltage being 240 VAC.

With a significant current load on the utility lines (or inside the house) the voltage will drop.

Motors, which can draw a lot of current, are generally rated at 110 VAC or 220 VAC. This simply states that they will run even if there is 10V (or 20V) drop in voltage.

At the breaker box, 120 VAC circuits generally only have three wires: one Line, the Neutral, and a Ground. The Neutral is current-carrying, but the Ground only carries current if there is an electrical fault.

Interestingly, in the past, 240 VAC circuits also had only three wires. Some had L1, L2, and N, to allow for small 120 VAC loads within an appliance. Motor loads would often have L1, L2, and GND, with no Neutral connection at all.

Now, however, I believe all 240 VAC receptacles are supposed to have all four conductors.

---

Regarding the second part of your question, the devices don't actually know which phases are hot, which are neutral, etc. They only see the potential difference between the two power wires.

So, in a 120V circuit, one wire (Line) has 120 VAC and the other (Neutral) has 0 VAC. The difference is 120VAC.

In a 240 VAC circuit, one wire has 120VAC and the other has 120VAC at the opposite phase. The difference is then 240 VAC.

Answer (score 0):

the wiring is like this

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fj1ut9.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>